# Storing JSON reply payload object in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, json, ssjs

I'm successfully getting a result from an HTTP.Post call.

My reply comes in a form of a JSON and looks something like this:

```
{
"Result": {
    "Message": "",
    "MessageDetails": "",
    "Status": 1
},
"SessionGuid": "*********"
}
```

I'm trying to save the content of the SessionGuid into a data extension.

I have tried multiple things but nothing worked:

```
 var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
   var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result);
  var SessionGuid = accessToken.SessionGuid;
  write(SessionGuid);
 // var oResults = eval("(" + result[0] + ")");
 //  var sessionid = Results["SessionGuid"];
 //  var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result);
 // var  sessionid = result.SessionGuid;
 // var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(results);
 // write(sessionid);
 //var oresults = Stringify(result);
 //   Write(oresults);
 // var resultss = results["StatusCode"];
 // var sessionid = results.StatusCode;
 // Platform.Function.InsertDE("broker",["Response"],[sessionid]);
```

I left the things i tried in here so you can see.
Best thing I could get was to get the whole JSON reply in the DE, by Stringify-ing the result.

Thanks a lot,
Andrei

Comment: Are you receiving an error with any of these? Null values? etc. please provide more details

Comment: There are 3 types of replies: 1. I get a server 500 error. 2. I get null values. 3. I get the whole JSON payload in the de. I just need the value of the SessionGuid either in the DE or just to be written on screen at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried `result[0].SessionGuid`? I have found declaring the object number seems to be required for SFMC JSON returns - even when there is only 1 level.

Answer (score 0):

This is what did it for me:

```
var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);
  var accessToken = tokenResponse.SessionGuid;
    Write(accessToken);
```